# How to launch android.intent.action.CALL in service?

Tags: android, service, ussd

How to launch `android.intent.action.CALL` (to get USSD) code in service?

My Code:

```
protected void call(String phoneNumber) {
    try {
        startActivityForResult(
            new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                + phoneNumber)), 1);
    } catch (Exception eExcept) {
        //this.view.append("\n\n " + "\n" + eExcept.toString());
    }
}
```

This code does not work, the problem with `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: can you make your pasted code look right? if has the error log, plz also paste.

Comment: do you have the call permission in the manifest file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the intent for call

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneno));
   startActivity(intent);
```

& Dont miss the Add permission in Maniefiest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phoneNumber));
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     startActivity(intent);

Comment: It's still not working on Samsung Galaxy Ace (Android 2.3.6), please guide me.